# Add New Fields to Many Nested Objects In ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch, I have some nested data structured as follows:

```
{
  "hello_metadata": {
    "stuff": "123",
    "apple": "23423"
  },
  "aksdjj_metadata": {
    "stuff": "ppppppp",
    "apple": "ddddddd"
  }
}
```

I need to be able to add new fields to the mapping of all objects that match a certain phrase, in this case "_metadata".

For example, if I wanted to add a new field named "cheese" of type "text" to all objects containing the phrase "_metadata", then I would end up with:

```
{
  "hello_metadata": {
    "stuff": "123",
    "apple": "23423",
    "cheese": "akjsdadad"
  },
  "aksdjj_metadata": {
    "stuff": "ppppppp",
    "apple": "ddddddd",
    "cheese": "L"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do this using the [Update Mapping API][1]?

I cannot re-create the Index, I must UPDATE it so I do not believe I can use the Dynamic Templates.
[1]: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#indices-put-mapping

Answer (score 0):

You can use update mapping.

1. Create the new field

PUT demo-index/_mapping

```
 {
      "properties": {
        "hello_metadata": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "cheese": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

2. Update your document, using query if you want to target specific ones (containing _metadata for example).

Comment: This is not what I meant. I need to use the Update mapping API to update the mappings of all nested fields that contain _metadata, using something like a wildcard or regex. I do not want to update the actual documents.

Comment: I am not sure to understand. The mappings is the same for all documents in a same index. You mean update fields of documents containg _metadata?